# AngularJs: Adding input selected files into an array and displaying the files name in a ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an interesting question concerning AngularJs. I am attempting to create a dynamic list of image files which the user can add to an array before he/she submits them. I would like the added files name to be displayed in the list using ng-repeat.

```
<h5>Images</h5>                                        
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="image in images">
        {{image.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" data-ng-click="addImage()">ADD IMAGE</button>
```

Basically, the user clicks on the "add image" button above and the file selector dialog will appear. Once the user has selected a file, the details are added to the array. This all works fine... however, the ng-repeat directive is not updated. Why would this be?

```
app.controller('ImagesController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.images = [];
    };
    $scope.init();

    $scope.addImage = function() {
        input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = "file";
        input.onchange = function() {
            $scope.images.push({
                name: input.value.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop(),
                file: input.files[0]
            });
        };
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(input).click();
        }, 200);        
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This callback is happening outside of the scope of the Angular app.

Try adding `$scope.$apply();` after you push the new value in to manually fire the digest. There are sometimes better ways to do this, but this will at least confirm that it's the issue.

```
input.onchange = function() {
  $scope.images.push({
    name: input.value.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop(),
    file: input.files[0]
   });
  $scope.$apply()
};
```

Comment: Right you are. I knew it had something to do with scope.